# Is there a way to get Mel-frequency cepstrum coefficients of a track from the Spotify API?

Tags: spotify, mfcc, audio-analysis

I am looking to get the [MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)(Mel-frequency cepstrum coefficients) of a spotify track. My main aim is to identify genre of a track, and the algorithm which I'm studying right now uses MFCC to extract features of a track.

I think there might be 2 ways to do this:

1. Spotify's API has an endpoint called https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/{id}. [This](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=11b0c58523b7293834925c6f48b4f86e) is what the output looks like for a track. Maybe there is a way to get MFCC from this output?
2. Get raw audio features of the track from an API endpoint and then use a (different) library to apply MFCC on the features.

Or, is there any other method I can try?

Thanks :)

Edit :

- The output of audio-analysis API for a track given [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=11b0c58523b7293834925c6f48b4f86e) contains a key called "tmfccrack". Is this related to the MFCC?
- I found out that you can get the genre of a Spotify track by getting the genre of the corresponding artist through the Spotify API. That gets me what I want for now, but I think I should keep the question open because it asks for the MFCC of a track and not just the  genre.